# Potential Field in space of a "thick" dieletric spherical shell affected by an uniform electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

The spherical linear homogeneous dielectric shell has an inner radius $a$ and an outer radius $b$ and is under the influence of an uniform electric field, then what is the potential across all its regions?

What I have been able to deduce: First, due to the uniform electric field I am assuming that the polarization $\vec P$ is constant across the dieletric. Second, because there is no enclosed charge in $r<a$ the electric field is zero and thus the potential is some constant on that whole region. Then at large distance $r\gg b$ the potential will simply be a function of the uniform field which using polar coordinates $V_{r\gg b}=-E_0 r \cos\vartheta$.

I think that my biggest problem is that I dont really know how to quantify the polarization $\vec P$, which I suppose that I could use to discover the surface area charge density via $\sigma_P=\vec P\cdot\hat n$ and then use it to integrate. Do I also have to consider the compounding effects in which the electric field induces polarization which in turns amplifies the electric field and intensifies itself? It is rather confusing and I dont think I have been able to fully wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, you want to solve here a boundary value problem, but you seem to have an issue with setting the boundary conditions for you don't know $P$.The thing is, you need $\sigma$ to give you a boundary condition, which is determined using $P$. You do know this, $\sigma = \epsilon_{0} \chi_{e} E \cdot \hat n$ which is equal to $$\epsilon_{0} \frac{\partial V}{\partial n}_{below} - \epsilon_{0} \frac{\partial V}{\partial n}_{above}$$ on each of the surface (two). Simply exploit this: the boundary conditions now read:

1. ${V_{above}}_{r=a} = {V_{below}}_{r=a}$
2. ${V_{above}}_{r=b} = {V_{below}}_{r=b}$
3. A) $\epsilon_{0} \frac{\partial V}{\partial n}_{below} - \epsilon_{0} \frac{\partial V}{\partial n}_{above}= \sigma$ (for two surfaces, make sure you get the signs and the input correct)

B) $\sigma =\sigma_{b} =-\epsilon_{0} \chi_{e} \frac{\partial V_{above}}{\partial n} $ (for two surfaces, make sure you get the signs and inputs correct, and link 3a and 3b, which yields another equation)

(Also here there are no free charges, hence the subscript b)

4. Potential as $r \to \infty$ = $- E_{0} r cos(\theta)$

I guess this is enough to solve the problem, (intuition tells me you'll have 3 or 4 unknown coefficients in the spherical coordinates expansion).

Good luck !!